# Textbox allowed only 6 charactors length only C#.net

Tags: c#

i have to validate the textbox on c#.net.only allowed 6 charactor length other wise through error

```
if(textBox1.MaxLength > 6)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Username shound 6 Charactor length");
     textBox1.Clear();
  }
```

Comment: Could you pls give us your error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
if(textBox1.Text.Length > 6)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Username shound 6 Charactor length");
     textBox1.Clear();
  }
```

Comment: if is working make right..

Comment: sir how to check textBox1 and textbox2 both or same text like password and confirm password . pls reply

Comment: if(textBox1 .text !=textbox2 .text){ MessageBox.Show("Please enter same"); }

Answer (score 1):

You sould set a maxlenght to your textbox, with this solution it's useless to check lenght of your value, the lenght was always < 6 :

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 6;

//But you can use this code:

if(textBox1.Text.Lenght > 6)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username shound 6 Charactor length");
    textBox1.Clear();
}

//Your welcom
```

Comment: if I am set max length. then not work below code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check by `textBox1.Text.Length` instead of `textBox1.MaxLength`

You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength?view=netframework-4.8) to know what does `MaxLength` mean.

From that point, you no need to check length, Just set `MaxLength` value for `textBox1`

Comment: Feel free to contact me if you have any concerns. @deva ram

Comment: sir how to check textBox1 and textbox2 both or same text like password and confirm password

Comment: You just compare the value between 2 textbox, Like `if(textBox1.text == textbox2.text)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? @deva ram